# If statement for all except one

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am more familiar with JS than with PHP. What I would like to have, is a php condition that runs for all pages except one.

I would like below "only not for page ID 2":

```
function my_action() {
    if( is_page( 2 ) ) {
        // code here
    }
}
```

Does PHP cover also cover the `!` exception rule and if so; where do I put this?

Comment: _"Does PHP cover also cover the ! exception rule and if so; where do I put this?"_ - This is PHP 101 so I would recommend that you go through a bunch of PHP tutorials and learn the basics before you continue or you will most likely end up here again and again. You should also make it a habit to look at https://php.net when in doubt. In this case, you could simply have tested it and you would probably have gotten your answer quicker than it took you to post the question.

Comment: @ivar I have looked for it but I couldn't find the answer, and the question is also for my scenario; where do I put it? I am aware of how SO works, I just couldn't find it.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I couldn't find the answer, that's why I ended up here. And because it's a live webshop, I couldn't risk a 500 error due to a mistake, as this goes into functions.

Comment: Just create a PHP file locally and test the if-statement you want to test or even easier, use something like [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/). No need to test it on the live server. In [the manual about `if`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) there's also a link to [a detailed explanation about expressions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php). Read through that one.

Comment: @Demian I'd highly recommend setting up a local development environment. Even if you know where to place it, it's really easy to overlook something (either now or when you change something in the future). Personally I'd say that a development environment is the first level before you should put your site live. Not the other way around. Also Magnus provided a link where you can test it even without a local environment.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **!** with function too.
for example :

```php
<?php 
$x = null;
    if ( ! isset($x) {
       echo "null";
    } // result nothing because $x is available
?>
```